# Get OutOfMemoryError when using OccupancyGridLayer to display map

Tags: navigation, mapping, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I run my program on a real device with 1GB memory. I tried to use OccupancyGridLayer to display map message i got from robot. However, after about 10s processing, I got OutOfMemoryError and the app was forced to stop. Does anyone have the same problem? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38306/get-outofmemoryerror-when-using-occupancygridlayer-to-display-map/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-09**:
Could you include the map parameters for the map you trying to display (size in x and y, pixels/meter, etc)? Basically the MapMetaData that goes along with the OccupancyGrid message you are trying to display.

**Comment by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on 2012-07-09**:
Hi, thanks for the reply. Here is the data:
width = 428
height = 580
resolution = 0.025
map load time = 0:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the process of addressing this issue. See http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=131

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0